# Remove binary data from html file using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I have html file that have tags for binary data like:

```
<HTML>
  <BODY STYLE="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif">
    <TEXT>
      begin 644 image_002.jpg
        M_]C_X  02D9)1@ ! 0   0 !  #_VP!#  @&!@<&!0@'!P<)"0@*#!0-# L+
        M#!D2$P\4'1H?'AT:'!P@)"XG("(L(QP<*#<I+# Q-#0T'R<Y/3@R/"XS-#+_
        MVP!# 0D)"0P+#!@-#1@R(1PA,C(R,C(R,C(R,C(R,C(R,C(R,C(R,C(R,C(R
       ,Z4]1]: %HHHIB/_9
    end
   </TEXT>
   <TEXT>losses occurring in the third quarter and from weather  </TEXT>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

so I am trying to remove all "TEXT" tags those have binary data using Java Regex. I tried [Jsoup library](https://jsoup.org/) But it only remove html tags.  I saw the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378907/removing-binary-control-characters-from-a-text-file). But it is not using Java Regex.

Is any standard way to remove this binary data from html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   val regex =  """<TEXT>\s*begin \d+ (?>[^e]+|e(?!nd\s*<\/TEXT>))*end\s*<\/TEXT>"""
```

Full example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/enA1Ic/5)

Answer (score 1):

It is well know that you shouldn't use a regex to handle xhtml.

I would use jsoup to remove the whole tag and later add it empty.

But if you want to use a regex, then you can use a regex like this:

```
"your html here".replaceAll("(?s)<TEXT>.*?<\\/TEXT>", "<TEXT></TEXT>")
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/PUoWNT/1)**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am trying to remove only "<TEXT>" which have binary data. Not all tags.It is not working.

Comment: @Sky ok, update your question accordingly with sample of valid and non valid tags so I can update the answer to help you